# '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I have Developed VSTO Addin. Now When I am trying to Install VSTO Addin in my machine I am getting an Exception as following.

System.Xml.XmlException: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 21, position 39.

I have checked in .vsto file at line number 21. and The line is as following.

```
<publisherIdentity name="CN=&quot;&lt;itranscript.net&gt;&quot;"/>
```

What is wrong in above line. Can anyone help me?

Comment: In XML entity notation '<' is "&lt;", but it does not occur at position 39. Strange! In cleartext your CN string is "<itranscript.net>". This is probably wrong. A CN value usually has neither quotes nor <> characters.

Comment: If un-escaped, the '<' would be at position 39

Comment: Are you sure < and > are allowed for your publisherIdentity element?

Comment: <publisherIdentity name="CN=&quot;&lt;itranscript.net&gt;&quot;"/> generated automatically in .vsto file

Comment: How do you generate manifest files? Using `Mage` tools?

Comment: Manifest is created when I have created Word Addins using VSTO Tool

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old, but it was the first thing that came up on my search here.
I had a similar issue , but it was due to a malformed element in a separate app_settings.config file, so it threw me, as the error was referring to the Web.Config.
So in the Web.config, there was something like this

```
<appSettings file="DebugPrimaryPaul_AppSettings.config">
```

and in the _AppSettings.config was something like this

```
<add key ="RegionalCodes" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx />
```

Note the missing " after value, which results in a malformed line.
The error was referring to a line in the Web.config much lower down. Putting the " in fixed it.

Comment: You just saved me an hour of flailing around. I was in the middle of a modification to the appSettings file yesterday and got pulled off. Totally forgot about it.

Answer (score 6):

The answer I was looking for was to replace `<` with `&lt;`

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. `<publisherIdentity name="CN=&quot;&lt;itranscript.net&gt;&quot;"/>` is not correct. Given the right value in name solved my issue...

Answer (score 0):

I use Elmah Error handling and have to insert entries manually when no HTTP_Context is available, i found the same issue with XML parsing, and fixed it with the inside detail of my message replacing, < with < and > with >

This managed to let the XML parser work ok.